# what is the difference between these two releases with and without the "-k419"?

Tags: android

I am trying to install Android-x86 OS on my PC. I found there are two different downloads:

**`cm-x86_64-14.1-r4.iso`** and **`cm-x86_64-14.1-r4-k419.iso`**

Can anybody tell me what are the differences between them (with k419 and without k419)?

You can find them on this site: https://osdn.net/projects/android-x86/releases

**EDIT:**

Probably that r419 represents the kernel version of 4.19.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

k491 = Android Kernel 4.9.1. So this version is a special build for that android kernel version built on the stable kernel from Linus's, in this case 4.9

Read more on this topic [here](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/kernel/releases)